# How to change `double` opacity in `tkz-tab` package

Tags: tkz-tab

This is my MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\pagecolor{yellow}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node style/.style={fill opacity=0,text opacity=1}]
        \tkzTabInit[espcl=1.75]{$x$/.5,$f'(x)$/.7,$f(x)$/1.5}{$-\infty$,$-2$,$-1$,$0$,$+\infty$}
        \tkzTabLine{,+,z,-,d,-,z,+,}
        \tkzTabVar{-/$-\infty$,+/$-3$,-D+/$-\infty$/$+\infty$,-/$1$,+/$+\infty$}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I set the `double` opacity to zero. Note that its default color is white.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just add `\tkzTabColors[backgroundcolor=yellow]`.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-tab} 
\pagecolor{yellow} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[node style/.style={fill opacity=0,text opacity=1}] 
\tkzTabColors[backgroundcolor=yellow]
\tkzTabInit[espcl=1.75]{$x$/.5,$f'(x)$/.7,$f(x)$/1.5}{$-\infty$,$-2$,$-1$,$0$,$+\infty$}
\tkzTabLine{,+,z,-,d,-,z,+,} 
\tkzTabVar{-/$-\infty$,+/$-3$,-D+/$-\infty$/$+\infty$,-/$1$,+/$+\infty$}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I chose yellow page for illustration. What I do need is not changing `double` color! I actually want it transparent.